# Multivariate Optimization of 3d Points With Known Relations

Tags: python

Given a set of data representing points in a 3d space

| Id | pos x | pos y | pos z | rot x | rot y | rot z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 20 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 80 | 10 |

We want to tweak each row's column value, and then compute each row against one another to end up with a delta that's as close to known deltas as possible.

For example -

We will start with this set of **known deltas** -

| Comparison Ids | delta pos x | delta pos y | delta pos z | delta rot x | delta rot y | delta rot z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 - 2 | 0 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 - 3 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 - 2 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 10 | 20 | 60 |

We will then want to tweak the 3d point values, calculate the deltas between each rows values, and do this until we can find the optimal **3d point values** which produce delta values that are the closest to the known deltas.

**Newly calculated deltas** after tweaking the 3d points values -

| Comparison Ids | delta pos x | delta pos y | delta pos z | delta rot x | delta rot y | delta rot z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 - 2 | 0 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 - 3 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 - 2 | 2 | 5 | 2 | 12 | 20 | 50 |

How similar are the the newly calculated deltas with the known deltas? Keep tweaking until we can find the most similar average of all the deltas.

Hopefully the describes the problem well enough. I hugely appreciate any insight on how this could be done, possibly with scikit-learn. Thank you.